# List next to block of text and image in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to keep a list block (used for navigation) inline with with a block of text which also contains an image. My current issue is that it appears to work until I expand the browser to the full screen size at which point the list sits on top of the block of text. **HTML Code:**

```
<body>
     <ul>
          <li>Something1</li>
          <li>Something2</li>
          <li>Something3</li>
     </ul>
<div>
     <section>
          <img>
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
     </section>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
ul{
    width:15%;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid black;
}

section{
    width:80%;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: What's the styling on the `<div>`?  Apply the width and float to the div.

Comment: @sideroxylon there is no styling on <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply this code here:

```
ul, section {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul{
    width:15%;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    border:2px solid black;
}

section{
    width:80%;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:0;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

When using `border-box` the padding and border will reduce the width of the element that `width + padding + border` equals the `width` of the content of that element.

When you float elements you should always make them `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.

The problem with your code is that the border affects the width of your element too - this is a problem when it comes to % width because your element will be `x% + border`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yo6h4xjg/)

**Edit**

Something like this? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32a4eaqo/) for advanced layouts have a look at: [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Note: And, as another user mentioned, you should only use `float` on elements on the same level (both elements have the same parent).

Comment: F. Mueller, your solution appears to work! Thank you very much. I do have one last question. Is there a way to close the gap that is between the ul and section components? I have the widths set to 15% and 80% respectively. I've fiddled around with those percentages, but I cannot find an easy way to have a smaller gap other than increase 80% to something like 83%.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem I guess is that you are not calculating the padding of the `ul`, try setting `padding: 0;` otherwise you get more the 100% `width` in total and the `div` slides under the `ul`. BTW why are you wrapping a `section` in a `div`?